# Error while sending file to dropbox

Tags: python-3.x

**Hi Guys, 
I am trying to send a file to dropbox with thise code:**

```
import dropbox

f = open('test.txt')

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('ACCESS TOKEN')

dbx.files_upload(f, '/uploaded.csv')

f.close()
```

**However, I am having this error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erim\Desktop\aa.py", line 7, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(f, '/uploaded.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Erim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 1267, in files_upload
    f,
  File "C:\Users\Erim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 234, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Erim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 325, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Erim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 369, in request_json_string
    type(request_binary))
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

**Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?**
**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't authenticating your app correctly?

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK
import dropbox

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
app_secret = 'INSERT_APP_SECRET'

flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python